# Быстро парсить страницу

Tags: синтаксический-анализ, регулярные-выражения, php, http, get

Функция `file_get_contents` работает, однако, зверски медленно. Есть ли другой, более быстрый способ, если я после получения данных обрабатываю их регулярками?

Answer (score 1):

Может не `get_file_contents`, а `file_get_contents`? В PHP более быстрого способа, чем стандартные функции, нету. И скорее всего, как раз регулярки и действуют медленно, а не функция. Попробуйте их максимально упростить, если возможно.

Comment: да, вы правы, я перепутал, но суть вопроса не меняется

Answer (score 0):

Парсил как то сайт поставщика. Тоже медленно было. В итоге разделил код на два файла. Один сохраняет инфу, второй парсит сохранённую информацию. Так как сохранение страниц проходило быстрее, парсер сохранённых данных запускал в несколько потоков.
Само сохранение происходило не через file_get_contents, а использовалась библиотека cURL.